# Browzer adds paragraph elements inside script

Tags: javascript, tags, paragraph

I am new to web developing, and I have met this problem. I write the following script:

```
<script>
function updateProductQuantity(num,index)
{
    var inp = document.getElementById("input-"+index);
    var tot = document.getElementById("total-"+index);
    var n_quantity = inp.value;

    if (!isNaN(n_quantity))
    {
        addArticle(num, null, {"quantity":"set_"+n_quantity});
        inp.value = parseInt(inp.value);
    }
    else window.alert("Not a number: " + n_quantity);
}
</script>
```

In chorme, (also firefox) this appears like this:

```
<p>&nbsp;<script>
function updateProductQuantity(num,index)
{
var inp=document.getElementById("input-"+index);
    var tot=document.getElementById("total-"+index);
    var n_quantity=inp.value;</p>
    <p> if (!isNaN(n_quantity))
    {
        addArticle(num,null, {"quantity":"set_"+n_quantity});
        inp.value = parseInt(inp.value);
    }
    else window.alert("Not a number:" + n_quantity);
}
</script></p>
```

(both firefox and chrome insert these p tags)

In the browzer, the whole script appears to be inside a "p" element, which I do not write in the code.
Also, the empty lines of my code are converted into p tags.
Of course, the script is broken and I get this error:
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

A workaround is to remove all empty lines from the come. But I dont think this is a solution. Right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your `index`? - `("input-"+index);`

Comment: sorry... I was changing the names trying to find what is the problem. I fix the variable names correctly. The problem remains..

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code my best guess would be that you've got something else going on like an unclosed tag that is confusing matters.

Try putting the contents of your file through W3C's validator https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and fix any errors that it is showing you

Comment: The whole code is here: view-source:http://www2.internet4me.at/shop/

It is a huge wordpress generated code before this script.
In every other page of the website, there is no problem. Only in mine.

The script that I posted is the first thing to appear in the page (after the wordpress stuff)

Comment: the W3C validator shows me some warnings and errors, but none of it is in my code, and no unclosed elements. All are in the wp header or footer. But the rest of the pages (with the same wp header and footer) are working normally. I do cannot understand where there p tags are coming from..

Comment: Are you adding the page content to a post? If you are wordpress automatically wraps text up in html to protect itself so you need to get the script into the header which can be done by modifying your header.php file in the template. Take a look at this at this link for more help https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: Ok I will check it out! Thanks a lot!!